# Bootstrap 3.4 on Shopify Debut Theme. Refusing to set backdrop to transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, shopify

I have this code calling the modal from my theme.liquid file it is right before the `</body>` tag. The backdrop does not want to be set to transparent.

If you look at the screen shot below it seems the backdrop is way bigger then the modal box as it does not cover the height of the screen and at the bottom of screen the background is visible.

[image: Screenshot of backdrop not transparent and larger then the modal pop up]

```css
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-out
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0)
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  outline: 0
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  /* background-color:#000;*/
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5
}

.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -2px
}

.modal-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5
}

.modal-footer .btn+.btn {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 5px
}

.modal-footer .btn-group .btn+.btn {
  margin-left: -1px
}

.modal-footer .btn-block+.btn-block {
  margin-left: 0
}

.modal-scrollbar-measure {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto
  }
  .modal-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  }
  .modal-sm {
    width: 300px
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 900px
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha512-pli9aKq758PMdsqjNA+Au4CJ7ZatLCCXinnlSfv023z4xmzl8s+Jbj2qNR7RI8DsxFp5e8OvbYGDACzKntZE9w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<!-- Modal popup - Discount -->
<div class="modal fade" id="discountModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="discountModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="https://d1wnwqwep8qkqc.cloudfront.net/uploads/stage/stage_image/47653/optimized_large_thumb_stage.jpg">
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-iztkobsvnjKfAtTNdHkGVjAYTrrtlC7mGp/54c40wowO7LhURYl3gVzzcEqGl/qKXQltJ2HwMrdLcNUdo+N/RQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function delaymodaltime() {
      $('#discountModalCenter').modal('show');
    };
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      delaymodaltime();
    }, 4000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you applying so many custom styles to the modal? Seems like that would make life difficult. FYI, you don't need all those vendor prefixes for `transform`.

Comment: I can't tell what I'm looking at in the screenshot. Is your question how to remove the black mask from the backdrop?

Comment: @isherwood I need to have the backdrop transparent. But in the screenshot it looks like the backdrop maybe larger then the modal pop up ? hence you can see the background where it breaks at the bottom. Hope that makes sense. I want to have it transparent.

Comment: The backdrop's _supposed_ to be larger than the modal. That's what a backdrop is.

Comment: I have tried removing it by doing: 
'.modal-backdrop{

}' but there is no change

Comment: '.modal{
   position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1050;
   background-color: transparent !important;  
}' this fixed it!